# How to install ionic@beta on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have my npm using this command `sudo apt-get install npm` and my version is `3.5.2` .

I have my nodejs installed with this command `sudo apt-get instlal nodejs` and my version is `v4.2.6` .

after this installation i try to install ionic2 from their offical blog

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/

I followed the command `npm install -g ionic@beta` but i am getting error as

```
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/panini/npm-debug.log
```

what is wrong i not able to see my version for ionic.

Comment: You quite possibly forgot `sudo` in `sudo npm install ionic@beta`

Comment: if use this one this means i should use sudo to create an project also

Comment: no, you won't have to.

Comment: Ok i did as you said i used `sudo npm install -g ionic@beta` and then i try to get the version in terminal `ionic -v` but i am not able to get the version i am getting this `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Comment: can you help me to install android sdk and where it should be located